# Annotation that edits the values ​of all properties of a Java class

Tags: java

Does anyone have an example where I can create a note that edits the values ​​of all properties of a Java class.

**For example @Car:**

Transform all fields to UPPERCASE;

```
@Car
public class Car {

    String name;
    String yaer;
    String engine;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Annotations are just static information. They do not modify the Java class but the interpreter code that scans them can do this.

One example would be [Project Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) which provides `@Getter` and `@Setter` annotations to generate methods based on field names. Since Java properties are usually recognized from method names you could implement your own version of Lombok annotations and create uppercase getter and setter.

You most likely would have to define your own [`javac` annotation processor](https://projectlombok.org/contributing/lombok-execution-path).

Comment: I understand thank you. I'll look at the Lombok Project

Comment: @EdeGerSil Check Lombok `@FieldDefaults` which adds the `final` modifier to fields. It's similar use case to what you have proposed.